# Looking for a way to consolidate multiple rows of time off requests to ranges in one row based off dates requested

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to consolidate some Time off requests from multiple rows into one row which identifies the start and end time. The current table looks similar to the following;

| ID | hours per day | Submitted Date | Requested Date | Requested Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 'Joe' | 8 | '2017-12-01' | '2017-12-05' | 'Approved' |
| 'Joe' | 8 | '2017-12-01' | '2017-12-06' | 'Approved' |
| 'Joe' | 4 | '2017-12-01' | '2017-12-07' | 'Declined' |
| 'suzie' | 8 | '2018-09-08' | '2017-12-24' | 'Approved' |
| 'suzie' | 8 | '2018-09-08' | '2017-12-25' | 'Approved' |
| 'Joe' | 2 | '2017-12-01' | '2017-12-7' | 'Approved' |

I'm trying to condense this into the following:

| ID | Total Hours | Submitted Date | Requested Date Start | Requested Date End | Requested Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | 16 | '2017-12-01' | '2017-12-05' | '2017-12-06' | Approved |
| Joe | 4 | '2017-12-01' | '2017-12-07' | '2017-12-07' | Declined |
| suzie | 16 | '2018-09-08' | '2017-12-24' | '2017-12-25' | Approved |
| Joe | 2 | '2017-12-01' | '2017-12-07' | '2017-12-07' | Approved |

I've tried dozens of things utilizing  partitions but i'm not really getting anywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [(minimal) complete example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). See the help center for more on [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and many other helpful topics.

Comment: What logic puts Joe's request of 2 hours off in a separate row from the other 16 hours? The sample table data doesn't seem sufficient for a query to make this determination.

Comment: @outis The 2 hour and 16 hour records in the output belong to separate _islands_.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: right. My question is how are those islands defined. None of the fields in the sample data establishes a sequence that can be used to make that determination. The only possibility based solely on what's given is that it's based on the storage order, which, as that's both external to the data and not stable, is problematic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  Assuming you are using MySQL 8+ we can use the difference in row numbers method here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY RequestedDate) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, RequestedStatus
                                 ORDER BY RequestedDate) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, SUM(hoursperday) AS total_hours, SubmittedDate,
       MIN(RequestedDate) AS rd_start, MAX(RequestedDate) AS rd_end,
       RequestedStatus
FROM cte
GROUP BY ID, SubmittedDate, RequestedStatus, rn1 - rn2
ORDER BY ID, RequestedStatus, MIN(RequestedDate);
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo